# Import a scss file into an angular library typescript file

Tags: angular, typescript, sass, angular-library

I have an angular workspace with a library and an application which will consume that library.

I am trying to import a .scss file into a .ts typescript file inside the library.

So I added a file called global.d.ts to the src dir of the library with the following content

```
declare module '*.scss' {
  const content: { [className: string]: string };
  export = content;
}
```

then I referenced it in tsconfig.lib.json file of the lib like so:

```
"include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
```

But this configuration doesn't work for me since the error "Cannot find module 'path-to-scss-file.scss' or its corresponding type declarations" is shown when trying to build the lib.

Ps: the same configuration works fine if I import a .scss file inside the application project and the problem occurs only inside the library.